# Google Books Api isbn code mismatch

Tags: google-api, google-books

I have a strange problem when I try to find a book by isbn code.

When I try to search it in the google books website I have this result:

[image]

And it's ok. But when I try to search this same isbn code with a request to google books api as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:8841274573
```

In response I have this result completely different with the search with google web site and my goal:

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "F1mCAQAACAAJ",
   "etag": "h72WBWNyItw",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/F1mCAQAACAAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Kitāb al-Thiqāt",
    "authors": [
     "Muḥammad Ibn Ḥibbān"
    ],
    "publishedDate": "1988",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "OTHER",
      "identifier": "OCLC:33995748"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": false
    },
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
     "Hadith"
    ],
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "preview-1.0.0",
    "panelizationSummary": {
     "containsEpubBubbles": false,
     "containsImageBubbles": false
    },
    "language": "it",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.it/books?id=F1mCAQAACAAJ&dq=isbn:8841274573&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.it/books?id=F1mCAQAACAAJ&dq=isbn:8841274573&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/Kit%C4%81b_al_Thiq%C4%81t.html?hl=&id=F1mCAQAACAAJ"
   },
   "saleInfo": {
    "country": "IT",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
   },
   "accessInfo": {
    "country": "IT",
    "viewability": "NO_PAGES",
    "embeddable": false,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://books.google.it/books/reader?id=F1mCAQAACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "NONE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way for distinguish (maybe in request parameter) a different book which have a different isbn?

In [documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list) there aren't any reference with this special parameter. (If it exists)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more one year, seems that Google has corrected this issue and if I try to call the API, the response is coherent now with my request presented in my initial question.